# Map between LaTeX commands and Unicode points

Tags: unicode, latex

Is anyone aware of where I could find a table mapping LaTeX commands to Unicode code points? eg: `\le` is 0x2264. I'm looking for something as comprehensive as possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The document I've used before is [this XML file](http://www.w3.org/Math/characters/unicode.xml) from the W3C. It maps Unicode to HTML, MathML, LaTeX, Mathematica, and others.  (The file is 1.4 MB, uncompressed.)

You can read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/

Comment: Genius! Been looking for this for ages. So helpful!

Comment: In case anyone needs this often (like me), I've made a little web app to make searchier easier than plow through that XML file: https://digitalheir.github.io/mathy-unicode-characters/

Answer (score 5):

I once cooked up this for a report generator written in Java (hence the Java String literals):

```
'\\'(REVERSE SOLIDUS)   "\\textbackslash{}"
'^'(CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT)  "$\\uparrow$"
'_'(LOW LINE)   "\\textunderscore{}"
'|'(VERTICAL LINE)  "\\vline{}"
'~'(TILDE)  "\\textasciitilde{}"    "~"
'§'(SECTION SIGN)   "\\S{}"
'ª'(FEMININE ORDINAL INDICATOR) "$^a$"
'­'(SOFT HYPHEN)    "\\-"
'²'(SUPERSCRIPT TWO)    "$^2$"
'³'(SUPERSCRIPT THREE)  "$^3$"
'·'(MIDDLE DOT) "$\\cdot$"
'¹'(SUPERSCRIPT ONE)    "$^1$"
'º'(MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR)    "$^o$"
'\u013a'(LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH ACUTE)   "\\'l"
'\u013b'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH CEDILLA)   "\\c{L}"
'\u013c'(LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH CEDILLA) "\\c{l}"
'\u013d'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH CARON) "\\v{L}"
'\u013e'(LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH CARON)   "\\v{l}"
'\u013f'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH MIDDLE DOT) "L\\hspace{-0.35em}$\\cdot$"
'\u0140'(LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH MIDDLE DOT)  "l$\\cdot$"
'\u0141'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE)    "\\L{}"
'\u0142'(LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE)  "\\l{}"
'\u0143'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH ACUTE) "\\'N"
'\u0144'(LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE)   "\\'n"
'\u0145'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH CEDILLA)   "\\c{N}"
'\u0146'(LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH CEDILLA) "\\c{n}"
'\u0147'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH CARON) "\\v{N}"
'\u0148'(LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH CARON)   "\\v{n}"
'\u0149'(LATIN SMALL LETTER N PRECEDED BY APOSTROPHE)   "'n"
'\u014c'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH MACRON)    "\\={O}"
'\u014d'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON)  "\\={o}"
'\u014e'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH BREVE) "\\u{O}"
'\u014f'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH BREVE)   "\\u{o}"
'\u0150'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE)  "\\H{O}"
'\u0151'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE)    "\\H{o}"
'\u0152'(LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE) "\\OE{}"
'\u0153'(LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE)   "\\oe{}"
'\u0154'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH ACUTE) "\\'{R}"
'\u0155'(LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH ACUTE)   "\\'{r}"
'\u0156'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH CEDILLA)   "\\c{R}"
'\u0157'(LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CEDILLA) "\\c{r}"
'\u0158'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH CARON) "\\v{R}"
'\u0159'(LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CARON)   "\\v{r}"
'\u015a'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH ACUTE) "\\'S"
'\u015b'(LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH ACUTE)   "\\'s"
'\u015c'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CIRCUMFLEX)    "\\^{S}"
'\u015d'(LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CIRCUMFLEX)  "\\^{s}"
'\u015e'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA)   "\\c{S}"
'\u015f'(LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA) "\\c{s}"
'\u0160'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON) "\\v{S}"
'\u0161'(LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON)   "\\v{s}"
'\u0162'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH CEDILLA)   "\\c{T}"
'\u0163'(LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH CEDILLA) "\\c{t}"
'\u0164'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH CARON) "\\v{T}"
'\u0165'(LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH CARON)   "\\v{t}"
'\u0168'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH TILDE) "\\~{U}"
'\u0169'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH TILDE)   "\\~{u}"
'\u016a'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH MACRON)    "\\={U}"
'\u016b'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH MACRON)  "\\={u}"
'\u016c'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH BREVE) "\\u{U}"
'\u016d'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH BREVE)   "\\u{u}"
'\u016e'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE)    "\\r{U}"
'\u016f'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE)  "\\r{u}"
'\u0170'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE)  "\\H{U}"
'\u0171'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE)    "\\H{u}"
'\u0172'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH OGONEK)    "\\k{U}"
'\u0173'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH OGONEK)  "\\k{u}"
'\u0174'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W WITH CIRCUMFLEX)    "\\^{W}"
'\u0175'(LATIN SMALL LETTER W WITH CIRCUMFLEX)  "\\^{w}"
'\u0176'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH CIRCUMFLEX)    "\\^{Y}"
'\u0177'(LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH CIRCUMFLEX)  "\\^{y}"
'\u0178'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) "\\\"Y"
'\u0179'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH ACUTE) "\\'Z"
'\u017a'(LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH ACUTE)   "\\'z"
'\u017b'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH DOT ABOVE) "\\.{Z}"
'\u017c'(LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH DOT ABOVE)   "\\.{z}"
'\u017d'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON) "\\v{Z}"
'\u017e'(LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON)   "\\v{z}"
'\u01CD'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CARON) "\\v A"
'\u01CE'(LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CARON)   "\\v a"
'\u01CF'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH CARON) "\\v I"
'\u01D0'(LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH CARON)   "\\v \\i{}"
'\u01D1'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CARON) "\\v O"
'\u01D2'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CARON)   "\\v o"
'\u01D3'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH CARON) "\\v U"
'\u01D4'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CARON)   "\\v u"
'\u01D5'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON)  "\\=Ü"
'\u01D6'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON)    "\\=ü"
'\u01D7'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND ACUTE)   "\\'Ü"
'\u01D8'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND ACUTE) "\\'ü"
'\u01D9'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND CARON)   "\\v Ü"
'\u01DA'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND CARON) "\\v ü"
'\u01DB'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND GRAVE)   "\\` Ü"
'\u01DC'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND GRAVE) "\\` ü"
'\u01DE'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON)  "\\= Ä"
'\u01DF'(LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON)    "\\= ä"
'\u01E6'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G WITH CARON) "\\v G"
'\u01E7'(LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH CARON)   "\\v g"
'\u01E8'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K WITH CARON) "\\v K"
'\u01E9'(LATIN SMALL LETTER K WITH CARON)   "\\v k"
'\u01EA'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH OGONEK)    "\\k O"
'\u01EB'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH OGONEK)  "\\k o"
'\u01F1'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER DZ)   "DZ"
'\u01F2'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH SMALL LETTER Z)    "Dz"
'\u01F3'(LATIN SMALL LETTER DZ) "dz"
'\u01F4'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G WITH ACUTE) "\\'G"
'\u01F5'(LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH ACUTE)   "\\`G"
'\u01F8'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH GRAVE) "\\`N"
'\u01F9'(LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH GRAVE)   "\\`n"
'\u01FA'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE AND ACUTE)  "\\'Å"
'\u01FB'(LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE AND ACUTE)    "\\'å"
'\u01FC'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE WITH ACUTE)    "\\'Æ"
'\u01FD'(LATIN SMALL LETTER AE WITH ACUTE)  "\\'æ"
'\u01FE'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE AND ACUTE)  "\\'Ø"
'\u01FF'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE AND ACUTE)    "\\'ø"
'\u0200'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)  "\\textdoublegrave{A}"
'\u0201'(LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)    "\\textdoublegrave{A}"
'\u0202'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH INVERTED BREVE)    "\\textroundcap{A}"
'\u0203'(LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH INVERTED BREVE)  "\\textroundcap{a}"
'\u0204'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)  "\\textdoublegrave{E}"
'\u0205'(LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)    "\\textdoublegrave{e}"
'\u0206'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH INVERTED BREVE)    "\\textroundcap{A}"
'\u0207'(LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH INVERTED BREVE)  "\\textroundcap{a}"
'\u0208'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)  "\\textdoublegrave{I}"
'\u0209'(LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)    "\\textdoublegrave{\\i}"
'\u020A'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH INVERTED BREVE)    "\\textroundcap{I}"
'\u020B'(LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH INVERTED BREVE)  "\\textroundcap{\\i}"
'\u020C'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)  "\\textdoublegrave{O}"
'\u020D'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)    "\\textdoublegrave{o}"
'\u020E'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH INVERTED BREVE)    "\\textroundcap{O}"
'\u020F'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH INVERTED BREVE)  "\\textroundcap{o}"
'\u0210'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)  "\\textdoublegrave{R}"
'\u0211'(LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)    "\\textdoublegrave{r}"
'\u0212'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH INVERTED BREVE)    "\\textroundcap{R}"
'\u0213'(LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH INVERTED BREVE)  "\\textroundcap{r}"
'\u0214'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)  "\\textdoublegrave{U}"
'\u0215'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)    "\\textdoublegrave{u}"
'\u0216'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH INVERTED BREVE)    "\\textroundcap{U}"
'\u0217'(LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH INVERTED BREVE)  "\\textroundcap{u}"
'\u0218'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW)   "\\textcommabelow{S}"
'\u0219'(LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW) "\\textcommabelow{s}"
'\u021A'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH COMMA BELOW)   "\\textcommabelow{T}"
'\u021B'(LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH COMMA BELOW) "\\textcommabelow{t}"
'\u021E'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H WITH CARON) "\\v{H}"
'\u021F'(LATIN SMALL LETTER H WITH CARON)   "\\v{h}"
'\u0226'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOT ABOVE) "\\.A"
'\u0227'(LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DOT ABOVE)   "\\.a"
'\u0228'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH CEDILLA)   "\\c E"
'\u0229'(LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CEDILLA) "\\c e"
'\u022A'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON)  "\\= Ö"
'\u022B'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON)    "\\= ö"
'\u022C'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH TILDE AND MACRON)  "\\makeatletter\\@tabacckludge={\\~O}\\makeatother{}"
'\u022D'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH TILDE AND MACRON)    "\\makeatletter\\@tabacckludge={\\~o}\\makeatother{}"
'\u022E'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DOT ABOVE) "\\.O"
'\u022F'(LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOT ABOVE)   "\\.o"
'\u0232'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH MACRON)    "\\=Y"
'\u0233'(LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH MACRON)  "\\=y"
'\u023A'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH STROKE)    "/\\hspace{-0.5em}A"
'\u023B'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH STROKE)    "/\\hspace{-0.5em}C"
'\u023C'(LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH STROKE)  "/\\hspace{-0.4em}c"
'\u023D'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH BAR)   "-\\hspace{-0.3em}L"
'\u023E'(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH DIAGONAL STROKE)   "-\\hspace{-0.3em}T"
'\u20AC'(EURO SIGN) "\\texteuro{}"
'\u2018'(LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) "'"
'\u2019'(RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) "'"
'\u201A'(SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK) "'"
'\u201B'(SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK) "'"
'\u201C'(LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) "\"{}"
'\u201D'(RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) "\"{}"
'\u201E'(DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK) "\"{}"
'\u201F'(DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK) "\"{}"
'\u025B'(LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E) "\\textepsilon{}"
'\u0283'(LATIN SMALL LETTER ESH)    "\\textesh{}"
```

But I'm pretty sure there isn't a *comprehensive* mapping anywhere - Unicode is HUGE. You'll probably have to compile and maintain it yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Very impressive list! Could you help to comment how to compile a more comprehensive list ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a web app based on the data mentioned above: http://www.johndcook.com/unicode_latex.html

Type in Unicode and it looks up the LaTeX symbol and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out my [LaTeX to Unicode converter](https://digitalheir.github.io/latex-to-unicode-converter/). It has a JavaScript API which you can use under MIT license. It is partially based on the W3C document shared earlier, but supports even more mappings that I gathered from here and there.

Most mappings are straightforward table lookups, but some commands have no or ambiguous Unicode equivalents. A comprehensive converter requires creative decisions. For example, fractions are quite complicated. `frac{5}{8}` produces `⅝`, `frac{5}{80}` produces ‌`5⁄80‌` and `frac{5}{80a}` produces `(5 / (80a))`).

Answer (score 0):

This is for the Word 2007 Equation Editor but it shares many similar commands with LaTeX: http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath.pdf

This huge table contains Unicode translation to LaTeX, MathML entities and Mathematica: http://www.ams.org/STIX/bnb/stix-tbl.asc98feb26